# Apple Watch VO2 Max is Very Low

Tags: running, cardio, health, heart-rate, vo2max

Does anyone else have an Apple Watch and/or iPhone that is reporting a very low VO2 max? I've never had mine tested and I haven't been running much lately, but a year or two ago I used to run 8 miles three times a week, so my cardiovascular fitness should be ok. However, my watch is reporting that my VO2 max estimate is 32.4 mL/(kg*min) which (for a 25 year old male) is very poor. I have a hard time believing my VO2 max could be that bad. I do have bad allergies and my heart rate naturally sits a bit higher than most, so I'm wondering if that is throwing it off or if I should be concerned.

Comment: Can you calibrate or compare it to another VO2 reading?

Comment: VO2 is based not on the total distance, but on the distance covered in a time unit.

Comment: I'm 63.  My VO2 Max is 26.8.  Sometime around 18 months ago, it dropped from normal to below normal rather quickly and for no apparent reason.  I'm trying to get it back up.  But, I have no way to verify if it is accurate or what.  All that to say that I question it.